# Why my condition with if statement is not execute correctly . android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a trouble with if statment in deleting some data from my cart .

I have some data in recyclerview in my cart fragment , also have a button for deleting all these data from cart .

I used a if statment to check if there is data(products) in the database or not .

When remove button is clicked if there is any data in database, Delete query is implemented and remove all data .  else there no data so just print a message for user : there is no product for deleting .

The problem is when if statment is execute and deleting successfully data , after that the else statment also executed . How could I prevent this ?

Code :

```
 CartFragment : Fragment ()



   val btnTrashAll: ImageButton = viewitem.findViewById(R.id.trash_icon_cart)

        getAllProductFromCart(btnTrashAll)



  fun getAllProductFromCart(button: ImageButton) {

        val animation: Animation =
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.anim_for_btn_zoom_out)
        button.setOnClickListener {

            button.startAnimation(animation)
            viewmodel.getAllFromCart().observe(this, Observer {

                if (!it.isNullOrEmpty()) {

                   val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(view!!.context)
                        .setMessage("Do you want to delete all ؟")
                        .setPositiveButton("yes") { dialog, which ->

                            viewmodel.deleteAllFromCart()

                            Toast.makeText(
                                view!!.context,
                                "Deleted Successfully .",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show() }
                        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                       .show()

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(
                        view!!.context,
                        "There is no Product for delete",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()


                }


            })


        }
```

Comment: `viewmodel.getAllFromCart().observe(this, Observer` this is observing onto something, which means that the code inside can be executed multiple times.

Comment: it's fine, you can post your own answer or just remove your question :)